# how to enable autocomplete in python IDLE 3.9.4 without third-party extensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

according to the python 3.9.4 documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) there is the ability for autocomplete without any external/third-party extensions for python IDLE (the default/official python programming that you download when installing python). I am new to programming. How do I enable the autocomplete that is mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enabled by default. It will only suggest auto-completions for things you've already coded (such as functions and variables), or for module methods, etc.

Comment: thank you! I was confused because pycharm does this and though IDLE did so as well.